# SSL Handshake issue when running using a JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, executable-jar, sslhandshakeexception

I am facing an issue while trying to run a RestClient through Java. 
I am using Apache HttpClient for building a rest client
I have added the required certificates in the jdk cacerts file and also checked that they are present there.

Now when I am running my code from eclipse than the handshake is happening correctly without any error and I am able to send a POST request.

Now when I create a runnable jar file from eclipse with all jars packaged in it than while running I am encountering the error 
Error Occurred: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Can you all please help me in resolving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your application with the following option:

```
java -Djava.security.debug=all ...
```

This will turn debugging on.

I'm assuming that your are running the jar file as a standalone application. If that is the case, the cacerts maybe different.

Comment: Thanks @JC Carrillo that really helped as I found out that the jar file was using another version of JDK other than the one used by eclipse so that was the problem.